# How can I fix a error when execute a sample code of http-conduit version 2.0.0.4

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

I am new to Haskell and am trying to a sample code of http-conduit version 2.0.0.4, but it dose not work

Here is the sample code

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Network
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar
import qualified Control.Exception as E

past :: UTCTime
past = UTCTime (ModifiedJulianDay 56200) (secondsToDiffTime 0)

future :: UTCTime
future = UTCTime (ModifiedJulianDay 562000) (secondsToDiffTime 0)

cookie :: Cookie
cookie = Cookie { cookie_name = "password_hash"
               , cookie_value = "abf472c35f8297fbcabf2911230001234fd2"
               , cookie_expiry_time = future
               , cookie_domain = "example.com"
               , cookie_path = "/"
               , cookie_creation_time = past
               , cookie_last_access_time = past
               , cookie_persistent = False
               , cookie_host_only = False
               , cookie_secure_only = False
               , cookie_http_only = False
               }

main = withSocketsDo $ do
    request' <- parseUrl "http://example.com/secret-page"
    let request = request' { cookieJar = Just $ createCookieJar [cookie] }
    E.catch (withManager $ httpLbs request)
            (\(StatusCodeException statusCode _ _) ->
              if statusCode==403 then putStrLn "login failed" else return ())
```

ref: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.0.0.4/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html

the error message when I load it

```
samplecode.hs:33:39:
    Couldn't match type `()'
                  with `Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
    Expected type: IO
                     (Response Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)
      Actual type: IO ()
    In the return type of a call of `putStrLn'
    In the expression: putStrLn "login failed"
    In the expression:
  if statusCode == 403 then putStrLn "login failed" else return ()

samplecode.hs:33:75:
    Couldn't match expected type `Response
                                    Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
                with actual type `()'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `()'
    In the expression: return ()
    In the expression:
      if statusCode == 403 then putStrLn "login failed" else return ()
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How can I fix it?

Many Thanks

**Update**

Following Abrahamson's advice,  I have changed my code little bit to the following and now have proper StatusCodeException handling.

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    request' <- parseUrl "http://example.com/secret-page"
    let request = request' { cookieJar = Just $ createCookieJar [cookie] }
    eitherResp <- E.try (withManager $ httpLbs request)
    case eitherResp of
      Left (StatusCodeException s _ _) 
        | statusCode s == 403 -> putStrLn "login failed"
        | otherwise         -> return () 
      Right resp -> print (L.length (responseBody resp))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `E.catch` as it was intended. If you take a look at the type:

```
E.catch :: Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a
```

it's clear that the return type of the first and second arguments must match. In your case you have

```
withManager $ httpLbs request :: IO (Response ByteString)
```

in the first branch and either

```
putStrLn "login failed" -- or
return ()
```

in the second. These types do not match and thus you're getting the error you see.

---

In higher level terms, the problem is that you're not handling the success case. For instance, we could rewrite this using `E.try` to make that more clear

```
eitherResp <- E.try (withManager $ httpLbs request)
case eitherResp of
  Left (StatusCodeException statusCode _ _)
    | statusCode == 403 -> putStrLn "login failed"
    | otherwise         -> return ()
  Right resp -> print (ByteString.length (responseBody resp))
```

Here since I explicitly pattern match on the `Either StatusCodeException (Response ByteString)` it's clear that I needed to provide both the failing and the succeeding branche and give them the same return types. To do so I introduced an action to perform on the successful case.

Generally, I find `E.try` easier to use. `E.catch` is primarily useful when you want to provide a *default* under failure.

Comment: A great answer, thank you for letting me your general case, I will read http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/error-handling.html to understand about try and catch,